# How do I handle clicks on a listBox in Haskells gi-gtk library

Tags: haskell, gtk3

I am experimenting with using Gtk and Haskell. And I got stuck. This link shows my experiments.
https://github.com/bigos/my-haskell-gtk-3-tutorial/blob/master/5-layout-containers.org#edit-the-source-2

I am trying to print the index of clicked list box row. The following code gives me a type error that I do not understand.

```
 onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\row -> putStrLn (listBoxRowGetIndex row))
```

I need an example where I can see how someone can properly handle the click events on the listBox rows.

### the error message

> Required ancestor ‘GI.Gtk.Objects.ListBoxRow.ListBoxRow’ not found for
>   type ‘Maybe GI.Gtk.Objects.ListBoxRow.ListBoxRow’. • In the first
>   argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely ‘(listBoxRowGetIndex row)’ In the
>   expression: putStrLn (listBoxRowGetIndex row) In the second argument
>   of ‘onListBoxRowSelected’, namely

Comment: can you post error msg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback argument type is `Maybe GI.Gtk.Objects.ListBoxRow.ListBoxRow`. It could be `Nothing` if nothing is selected. `listBoxRowGetIndex` has polymorphic type for its argument, so it tries to find instance for `Maybe GI.Gtk.Objects.ListBoxRow.ListBoxRow`, but there is no such instance. Minimal working code is

```
onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just row) -> listBoxRowGetIndex row >>= print)
```

But it is better to handle `Nothing` case properly considering application logic.

Comment: The constructor ‘Just’ should have 1 argument, but has been given none

Comment: @ruby_object Forgotten parentheses around pattern in lambda. I updated the answer

Comment: We are getting somewhere, I got this error now: Couldn't match type ‘GHC.Int.Int32’ with ‘Char’
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: [GHC.Int.Int32]

Comment: @ruby_object We are almost there. Error message is pretty explicit `listBoxRowGetIndex` returns list of numbers but `putStrLn` waits for `String`. You can "cast" anything showable to `String` with `show` - `putStrLn $ show $ listBoxRowGetIndex row` or you can use `print` as shortcut `print $ listBoxRowGetIndex row`

Comment: onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just row) -> putStrLn $ show $ listBoxRowGetIndex row)  gives this error: Ambiguous type variable ‘m0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show
                              (m0 GHC.Int.Int32))’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘m0’ should be.

Comment: @ruby_object I checked Hackage doc. `listBoxRowGetIndex` is not pure function. So we have to use IO monad - `onListBoxRowSelected listbox2 (\(Just row) -> listBoxRowGetIndex row >>= print)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161555/discussion-between-ilya-rezvov-and-ruby-object).

Comment: Ilya Rzvov's suggestions have worked. How should I update the question so it helps the next person with the same question?